# Pasta drawable vazia Android Studio - Não aparece nenhuma das opções de resolução

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

Criei um novo projeto no Android Studio Versão 1.3.2 e não aparece nenhuma das pastas que específica as resoluções correspondentes a elas ex: Drawable-hdpi, Drawable-ldpi.

Já mudei a forma de visualização de Android para Package como solução que encontrei em alguns tutoriais com esse problema e nada aconteceu e pelo visto até para esses que tentaram essa solução anteriormente nao conseguiram resolver, alguém tem a solução real para esse problema?

Comment: Helton, não há problema nenhum nisso, você pode e deve criar as pastas. O próprio Android Studio facilita a criação das mesmas.

Comment: As pastas são criadas quando você "joga" uma imagem lá (você mesmo pode criar, de fato).

Comment: Pessoal desculpa a demora, realmente de fato não há problema em criar, mas como já havia utilizado algumas vezes sem precisar fazer isso, achei um pouco estranho.

Grato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode mudar para a visualização Project e verificar se as pastas estão lá. Caso não estejam, simplesmente as crie.

[image]

Após isso, se não puder visualizar as pastas como segue:

[image]

Basta você criá-las. Botão direito do mouse em res -> new -> directory

E aí você insere o nome:

[image]